# Controlled partitioning and MapStore

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Lets say, I have several Hazelcast members (servers) spread across world (e.g. Germany, Russia and etc).

It was required to store/split data in database by region and all data should be accessible from any server via `IMap` backed by `MapStore`.

I recently read [this article](https://hazelcast.com/blog/controlled-partitioning/) which fulfills my requirement, but I am not sure about how will `MapStore` behave.

Crucial moment is that, if `member1` (e.g. Russia) requests data from `IMap` with key owned by `member2` (e.g. Germany), on which side `MapStore.load()` will be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not split members of the same cluster across different data centers.   Members of a cluster depend on a regular heartbeat message to detect the health of the cluster; wide area networks cannot reliably deliver these in a consistent fashion and you will almost certainly have network partition issues (split brain syndrome).

Each data center (Germany, Russia, etc.) should have a separate cluster with region-specific maps.   These maps can then be replicated (WAN replication) to the remote data centers both for disaster recovery and to provide a geographically close server to support users in that region needing access to the other region's data.

Since the data in the database is already split by region, matching this split on the Hazelcast side means that the MapLoader will always be loading from a database in the same location.

Comment: If every key in map is controlled by "Controlled Partitioning", how can network partition issues can appear? Since, partitioning is controlled, hazelcast will not try to rebalance memory across members. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If the cluster believes a member has crashed, the partitions belonging to that member will be reassigned (basically, whatever members held the backups of those partitions will be designated as primarys, and new backups will be created on other members).   Partition rebalancing and migration is a critical part of fault tolerance, maintaining cluster reliability in the case of a member crash.  In cases where members aren't co-located, there is a much greater chance of falsely believing a member has crashed, and then both the primary and the backup think they are primary (thus split-brain).

Comment: We developed our server with keeping that in mind and I am aware of split-brain problem. WAN replication is not what we need for now. We are limited with memory we can use, and we need that each member only holds own entries in his memory. It is acceptable if someone leaves/crashes, we handle those errors.

Comment: It would be nice if I get answer to my crucial question: if member1 requests data from IMap with key owned by member2, on which side MapStore.load() will be called?

Comment: The MapStore.load() will be called on the partition thread that manages the partition where the key would be found, so in this case on member2.