# Custom controlled partitioning

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I recently posted [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56475441/3675673) and I received full answer. But I am encountering another problem.

Case scenario is the same as in my recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56475441/3675673).

How can I configure member to own partition key?

e.g. `DataCenterOnRussia` partition key must always be owned by `member1` and `DataCenterOnGermany` partition key must always be owned by `member2`.

So `member2` could request data from `DataCenterOnRussia` using `PartitionAwareKey`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intent of the PartitionAwareKey is to allow for data affinity ... orders for a customer should be stored in the same partition as the customer record, for example, since they are frequently accessed together.

The PartitionAwareKey allows grouping items together, but not a way to specify the placement of those items on a specific cluster member.  (I guess if there were such a thing, it would likely be called MemberAwareKey).

A cluster in Hazelcast isn't a fixed-size entity; it is dynamically scalable, so members might be added or removed, and it is fault-tolerant, so a member could be lost without loss of the data that happened to be on that member.  In order to support those features, the cluster must have the freedom to move partitions around to different machines as the cluster topology changes.

Hazelcast recommends that all members of a cluster be similarly configured (equivalent memory configuration, most particularly) because of the idea that cluster members are interchangeable, at least as far as data storage.  (The MemberSelector facility does provide a provision for handling systems that have different processing capability, e.g., number of processor cores; but nothing similar exits to allow placement of specific data entries or partitions on a designated member).

If your use case requires specific placement on machines, it's an indication that those machines probably should not be part of the same cluster.

Comment: I guess, I have to implement logic in the way that, when Datacenter in Russia wants to access data on Datacenter in Germany, it should use Hazelcast client to access remote cluster.